# Looping through worksheet - Duplicate search values from array not written

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Hi I am fairly new to VBA and I am trying to achieve the following:

1. Read the value of a column of a workbook into an array
2. Open another workbook and in a worksheet look for these values in a column and copy the data in the adjacent columns in the worksheet.
   3.Write the data to the workbook in point 1

This is the function that I have written so far:

```
Function getDetailsFromMasterSheet(ByRef numberArray As Variant, ByRef flagNameArray As Variant, nameSuffix As String, flow As String)
Dim arrayIndex As Integer
Dim curCell As Long
Dim pathToFile As String
Dim pathToXl As String
Dim orderNumber As Integer
Dim classType As String
Dim classNumber As Integer
Dim className As String
Dim bNumber As Integer
Dim bName As String
Dim cNumber As Integer
Dim cName As String
Dim logic As String
Dim allowClear As String
Dim testFlagName As String
Dim flowName As String
Dim flowNameSuffix As String
Dim newWorkSheetName As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim sheetCount As Integer
Dim rowStart As Integer
Dim columnStart As Integer
Dim cellValue As String
orderNumber = 1
rowStart = 4
columnStart = 1
Dim retval As Boolean
pathToFile="C:\Projects\Project_Binning\Standard_Binning_J750HD_rev04.xlsx"
pathToXl = "C:\Projects\Project_Binning\MockDataBinning.xlsm"
logic = "S_ANY"
allowClear = "NO"
arrayIndex = 0

Set ws3 = Worksheets(newWorkSheetName)
Set ws = Workbooks.Open(pathToFile).Worksheets("Test")
ws.Activate
For curCell = 1 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
If ws.Cells(curCell, 8).Value <> vbNullString Then
  cellValue = ws.Cells(curCell, 8).Value
  If StrComp(cellValue, numberArray(arrayIndex), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
    classType = ws.Cells(curCell, 8).Offset(0, -7).Value
    classNumber = CInt(ws.Cells(curCell, 8).Offset(0, -6).Value)
    className = ws.Cells(curCell, 8).Offset(0, -5).Value
    If StrComp(flowNameSuffix, "LM", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        bNumber = CInt(ws.Cells(curCell, 8).Offset(0, -2).Value)
        bName = ws.Cells(curCell, 8).Offset(0, -1).Value
    Else
       bNumber = CInt(ws.Cells(curCell, 8).Offset(0, -4).Value)
        bName = ws.Cells(curCell, 8).Offset(0, -3).Value
    End If
    cNumber = numberArray(arrayIndex)
    cName = ws.Cells(curCell, 8).Offset(0, 1).Value
    ws3.Cells(rowStart, columnStart) = orderNumber
    ws3.Cells(rowStart, columnStart).Offset(0, 1) = classType
    ws3.Cells(rowStart, columnStart).Offset(0, 2) = classNumber
    ws3.Cells(rowStart, columnStart).Offset(0, 3) = className
    ws3.Cells(rowStart, columnStart).Offset(0, 4) = bNumber
    ws3.Cells(rowStart, columnStart).Offset(0, 5) = bName
    ws3.Cells(rowStart, columnStart).Offset(0, 6) = cNumber
    ws3.Cells(rowStart, columnStart).Offset(0, 7) = cName
    ws3.Cells(rowStart, columnStart).Offset(0, 8) = logic
    ws3.Cells(rowStart, columnStart).Offset(0, 9) = allowClear
    ws3.Cells(rowStart, columnStart).Offset(0, 10) = "'-" & flagNameArray(arrayIndex)
    arrayIndex = arrayIndex + 1
    rowStart = rowStart + 1
    orderNumber = orderNumber + 1
    End If
    End If
    Next curCell
    End Function
```

The data in the sheet from which I am copying is basically string and integers which has the format

classType, className, classNumber, bNumber, bName, cNumber, cName

Each of the data above is either a string or a number. These are copied into the variables which are in turn written to another worksheet

When there are no duplicate values in the number array, the code works as expected .i.e. the data gets read from the worksheet as expected and gets written to the expected worksheet. But, when there are duplicates in the array, only one of the values is considered and the rest are not. For example if the array consists of {65,75,65,80}. The value of 65 is written only once to the worksheet and the duplicate value is not.I checked to see if the array was getting populated correctly and it was. Not sure exactly as to what it is that I am doing wrong. Could anybody please let me know?

Comment: There are quite a few variables that you don't ever show being set. You also don't show any worksheet data at all. Please provide more information.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have added the information that you requested for

Comment: I still don't see where some variables such as `numberArray` are given values.

Comment: Apologies for that. I have now updated the code. This is basically a function and the numberArray gets passed to it from the calling function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue and was able to fix it. I noticed that in the for loop the control went from top to bottom and it happened only once. So, when the search condition was met once, it would never be met again. For example,
If the number 65 exists twice in the array, as soon as the number is found the writing to another worksheet task is done. But, what happens is if the number occurs again, since the iteration has already passed through the number 65 on the sheet once the number is never found  again. So, I added the following line of code

```
curCell = 1
```

at the end of the first if loop after

```
orderNumber = orderNumber+1
```

This set the control to the first row of the worksheet again and the duplicate numbers were successfully written to the worksheet!